# How to match whitespace in sed?

Tags: shell, sed

Suppose I have the following line in my file

```
range = a:123:234,b:333:333 (note there is a white space between the =)
```

I would like to replace 333:333 to something else by using sed

```
sed s/range\s=\sa:123:234,b:333:333/range\s=\sa:123:234,b:909:141/ -i myfile.txt
```

But the command above doesn't work.

Do I miss something?

Comment: I may be wrong, but in that case I think you can just use a space character instead of \s and put the whole string in quotes

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: I tried sed s/range\\ \\=\\ a:123:234,b:333:333/range\\ \\=\\ a:123:234,b:909:141/ -i myfile.txt but i get sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command

Comment: do: `sed "s/range = a:123:234,b:333:333/range = a:123:234,b:909:141/" -i myfile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed -i 's/\(range\s=\sa:123:234,b:\)333:333/\1909:141/' myfile.txt
```

Some key points:

1. When you point expressions like `\s` on the command line **unquoted**, the shell will interpret them first and then pass the result to sed.  Unless that is what you want, put such expressions in single quotes.
2. sed's substitute command looks like `s/old/new/` where `old` should be a regular expression, which may contain `\s` to mean whitespace, and `new` should be the replacement text.  The replacement text should **not** contain `\s` unless you want a slash-s in the output.
3. To save retyping, and therefore reduce the potential for bugs, the above captures the beginning part of the line as group 1.  This way, we can write it in the replacement text simply as `\1`.

#### Alternative

```
sed '/range\s=\sa:123:234,b:/ s/333:333/909:141/' myfile.txt
```

The above selects lines that contain `range\s=\sa:123:234,b:`.  For those lines and those lines only, it substitutes in `909:141` in place of the first occurrence of `333:333`.

Comment: To clarify the first point, replace `sed` with `echo` to see the actual argument that the shell is passing.

Answer (score 0):

Just with a simple [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command you can achieve the result, such as;

```
sed -i s/b:333:333/b:909:141/ myfile.txt
```

And if you so keen to use full line as pattern matching then use like this as follows;

```
sed s/range\ =\ a:123:234,b:333:333/range\ =\ a:123:234,b:909:141/ -i myfile.txt
```

Both will work same. Just use a `\` before spaces you wish to check for.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue:

```
awk -F: '/^range/{$(NF-1)="REPL1";$NF="REPL2"}1' OFS=':' input.txt
```

`-F:` splits the input line by colons into fields. Gives:

```
range = a
123
234,b
333
333
```

On lines starting with `range` we change the last `$NF` and the second last `$(NF-1)` field. The trailing `1` is an always true condition which makes awk print all lines.

`ORS=':'` tells awk to use the colon as output field delimiter.